# Drawing Prims algorithm Table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I want to draw the table attached. Searched the entire Website, tried strickthrough for lines through a table and tried tikzmark for arrows.

[image: DesiredResult]

Here is my MWE:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB
\documentclass[12pt ,hidelinks]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}% this stops indent of first line in paragraph
%\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
%\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{amsmath} % need for align environment 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathpazo} %and mathptmx package for extra large fonts
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{% <---- BEWARE
        \node[shape=circle, red,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{colortbl}% this colour cells

\begin{document}

\huge{Question 1}   
\vspace{2cm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{table}[!ht]  
    \centering
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}  
            \cline{2-8}
            \multicolumn{1}{c||}{}
        &    A   & B & C & D & E &F&G\\ \hline \hline
            A & - &  & 310& -&300& &620 \\ \hline
            B & - & - &550& 430&530 &\circled{330}&-\\ \hline 
            C & \circled{310} & 550 & - &-&350&-&-\\ \hline
            D & &430& - &-&-&210&390\\ \hline
            E& \circled{300} &530&350&-&- &380&360\\ \hline
            F&-&330&-&210&  \circled{380} &-&2.8 \\ \hline
            G&620&-&-&390& \circled{360}&-&-\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For something like this a [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) `matrix of nodes` is ideal. See section 59.1 of the manual for the full details.

Using a `matrix of nodes` you can produce:

[image]

using the code:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  Cells/.style={every node/.append style={#1},},
  border/.style={fill=SlateGray,text=white},
  main/.style={fill=DarkKhaki!20,
               rectangle,
               text height=1.4ex,
               text width=3ex,
               text depth = 0.4ex,
               align=center,
               anchor=base
  },
}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \matrix (M)[matrix of nodes,
          Cells=main,
          row sep=0.8mm,column sep=0.8mm,
          row 1/.style={Cells=border},
          column 1/.style={Cells=border},
      ]{
          & A & B & C & D & E & F & G \\
        A & - & - &310& - &300& - &620\\
        B & - & - &550&430&530&330& - \\
        C &310&550& - & - &350& - & - \\
        D & - &420& - & - & - &210&390\\
        E &300&530& - & - & - &380&360\\
        F & - &330& - &210&380& - & - \\
        G &620& - & - &390&360& - & - \\
       };
       \foreach \x in {2,...,8} {
         \draw[{Latex[]}-, thick, SlateGray]([yshift=0.5]M-1-\x.north)--++(0,0.5);
       }
        \draw[Tomato] (M-2-1.west)--(M-2-8.east);
       \foreach \c [count=\r from 3] in {7,2,7,2,6,6}{
          \draw[Tomato] (M-\r-1.west)--(M-\r-\c.west);
          \draw[Tomato] (M-\r-\c) ellipse [x radius=2.4ex,y radius=1.8ex];
          \draw[Tomato] (M-\r-\c.east)--(M-\r-8.east);
       }
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I have not gotten the colours quite right. The styling is a little special but easy enough to tweak.

The `(M)` after `\matrix` says that the cell in row `r` and column `c` of the matrix can be referred to as `(M-r-c)`. Of course, you can use anything instead of `M`. As above, the node coordinates `(M-r-c.north)` etc are very useful.

Comment: +1 but the red lines within the ovals are not beautiful :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Oops! Thanks for pointing this out. They weren't there when I last looked! A typo must have crept in. I'll fix.

Comment: Andrew, thank you so much for answering my question. I usually "appropriate code" from elsewhere on the site and then cobble it together, but this defeated me.

Comment: @user474859 Two comments: If you need people with tikz skills, use the appropriate tag, otherwise these folks won't see your questions. Second: When visiting this site frequently, can you change your username, please? This user1234 names make it difficult to get an impression of the person without looking at the profile pages.